# C++ update txt file method

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a code to update the content of some .txt files after i've done some operations over their content;This is the method. I have 2 cases. 
1)update of "dir.txt"
2)update of "ext.txt"
depends on param; In the void `main()` I perform operations over vectors ext and dir and now I want to delete all content of the file and rewrite a vector which has been modified; I already have a valid function to read from the file data and write it in the vectors;

```
void update(string type){
    vector<string>aux; string file; int nr=0;
    if (type=="dir"){
        for (int i = 0; i < this->dir_no; i++)
            aux.push_back(dir[i]);
        file = "directoare.txt";
        nr=dir_no;}
    else
        if (type == "ext"){
            for (int j = 0; j < ext_no; j++)
                aux.push_back(ext[j]);
            file ="extensii.txt";
            nr = ext_no;
    }

        else 
            return;
    if (f){ 
        f.close();
        f.open(file, std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc);
        for (int i = 0; i < nr; i++)
            f << aux[i] << "\n";
    }
    else cout << "Couldn't update! error " << endl;
}
```

PROBLEM: the code doesn't have any compilation errors but everytime i call it in main() function, cleans the content of my file without writting anything; I assume it's a silly logic mistake but I;ve been looking for hours at this point and I can't see it;btw f is a fstream which i declared in the class

Thank you for your help. I did update my code and started using strings because is something people tell me very often. I'm not really used to it so it's not my first option.I'm trying to change that.
Anyway,apparently using char was one part of the problem. The other one was that I hadn't close the file after writting to it. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Do not use `==` on `char*` and string literals. Use `strcmp` or make them `std::string`.

Comment: I suggest learning to use a debugger and stepping through your code. That will help you track down bugs way easier than asking here and is infinitely more useful than just analyzing your code.

Comment: Use a debugger or prints to find out which branches are being run. To me `if(type=="dir")` looks wrong, but then I grew up on C, so it could just be that I'm too old and C++ understands things like that these days...

Comment: The normal way to use if - else if - else is just like that: `if (...) { ... } else if (...) { ... } else { ... }` (note the use of `else if {}` instead of `else { if {}}`)

Comment: And really, *do* use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) for strings. Comparing pointers (arrays decay to pointers) just compares the pointers and not what they point to.

Comment: 1.) Why did you updated your code without any comments? 2.) Never ever update your code based on answers below

Comment: By the way, if `dir` and `ext` are vectors, you have two loops you can remove, just use assignment. And if `dir` and `ext` are *not* vectors, why? Also for the writing (which didn't happen *at all* with your code before your update) you can use `std::copy` with an `std::ostream_iterator`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)
instad of `char*` in C++

### **1. String comparsion**

You can't compare char arrays with `==`. You **have to** use [`strcmp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) instead.
You can use `operator==` with `std::string`.

---

### **2. If-else**

Should look like

```
if(...)
{
    //code
}
else if(...)
{
    //code
}
else 
{
    //code
}
```

---

### 3. Better formatting

Maybe you think that it's not that important, but it can definitly help you with debugging and it's a way better for future readers of your code (including you)